# Redirect or view stderr in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tf.keras

I'm trying to view the output of keras.backend.print_tensor in google colab.  Some people say that it goes to stderr, assuming IPython notebook is being run locally.

How does one view this output?  Or how do you redirect/view stderr in colab, while running in a web browser?

Comment: had you tried "!ls" on Colab?

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks!  I didn't know I could do that.  However, I still don't know how to solve the original problem.  BTW, right now, I don't need it any more, but I'm still curious.

Comment: Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @BobSmith, can you share a notebook that doesn't produce the issue?  It's not an 'issue'.  The result of the keras print function is always invisible, AFAIK.  Just give me the smallest counter example that actually works, so that we see the keras print() output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could execute the output of **`tf.keras.backend.print_tensor`** successfully in Google Colab with `Tensorflow Version 2.1`.

Mentioned below is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__  #2.1.0

x = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
tf.keras.backend.print_tensor(x)
```

Output is shown below:

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Here is the Link of the [Google Colab Gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/rmothukuru/e0a239c20b8a08a1cbae7ee5883d9656/so_59905087.ipynb).

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your solution is so simple that I'm wondering why I asked the question in the first place!  I have no idea if you fixed something or if it just worked, but many thanks.